# Ignore Assemblies In Xamarin.Android Linker

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, monodevelop, zxing, xamarin-linker

I'm getting an error when trying to build app with `Link SDK Assemblies Only`(everything works on `Don't Link`)

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Error executing task LinkAssemblies: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Element::set_AutomationId(System.String)' (defined in 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms, Version=2.1.47.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms, Version=2.1.47.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved. (FleetApp.Droid)

I'm trying to add assemblies that cause the issue in ignore list:

[image]

But I can't get the error disappear.
Is this correct way to do it? or am I adding wrong assemblies to ignore list?

P.S. Also tried adding them without braces.

Comment: Could you share some steps to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Create `Xamarin.Forms` app, downgrade `Forms` package to `2.0.5782`, install new version of `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms`. That should be enough

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of having an old version of `Xamarin.Forms`. You need to use the latest stable version of `Xamarin.Forms` as the dependency of `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms` does not strictly require you to have a version of `Xamarin.Forms` that doesn't include `AutomationId`.

Thus you would need >= `Xamarin.Forms` 2.2.0:

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-2.2/2.2.0-stable/#AutomationId_Support

After you do that, you can remove all the `Ignore Assemblies` as you no longer would need to ignore assemblies.

Comment: I know that, but I have worse issues on new Xamarin.Forms:
I get this: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/1125 and if I update XLabs to pre-release version than I get https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/1231 this. and can't get that fixed. so old version of xamarin.forms was a workaround

Comment: I can understand that, but the answer to your original question is you need Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0 or greater.

Comment: I would highly advise that you work off the most recent stable versions of Forms, XLabs, and ZXing. It's too hard to depend on old versions.